# How to disallow direct struct initialization

Tags: go

Given the following packages in Go, is it possible to prevent the direct initialization of  `Bar` with `Bar{..}` without de-exposing `Bar` from the package?

package `bar`:

```
package bar

import ()

type Bar struct {
    A string
    B string
}

func NewBar(baz string) Bar{
    return Bar{A:baz, B:baz+baz}
}
```

package `main`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "./bar"
)

func main() {
    x := bar.NewBar("sad") //all bars should be created with this
    y := bar.Bar{A: "fadss"} //and this should be disallowed
    bzzBar(x)
    bzzBar(y)
}

func bzzBar(bzz bar.Bar) { //but I can't do 'Bar -> bar' because I want to use the type
    fmt.Println(bzz)
}
```

My gut feeling says this can't be done, so that is also a valid answer.

Comment: While all the provided answers are sensible, I would add: do not treat the users of your package as idiots.  If you have a documented way of instantiating `Bar`s (via the `NewBar()`) function, just leave it as that and think of it as a contract between you and your users. Otherwise it's hard to draw a line somewhere: after all, using `unsafe` and `reflect` I'm able to do whatever I want to any instance of `Bar` no matter how it was instantiated.

Comment: In this case I am the idiot :). Bars all over the place and I would like to catch instances of this problem at compile time, so I don't run into fatals at runtime. And yes, I get that you can always get to the type, but then you explicitly did it to yourself, whereas doing a `Bar{..}` should create a valid Bar or break.

Comment: I see a couple of comments here along the lines of "you should trust the user (of our package) to do the right thing". While I think this is right, this question is also about right package design in terms of usability: As a user I would find it very frustrating to get fatals in a package because I instantiated a type incorrectly. I'd rather not have access to a type then being allowed to instantiate it wrongly.

Comment: My gut feeling (which seems to be supported by the answer of @VonC) is that "if a field must have a specific value with which the user can't mess directly, do not export it (and may be provide an accessor)". Sure, this can't be easily done in all cases.

Comment: Regarding initialization of private fields, you could also consider: http://dave.cheney.net/2014/10/17/functional-options-for-friendly-apis

Comment: If you want to have a language that is strong in compile-time invariant checking, Go is a bad choice for you. Many features for checking invariants at compile time are deliberately left out to keep the language simple, which is a good thing in my opinion.

Comment: @FUZxxl: did much python before this, so go is solid as a rock for me :) No need for academic languages here, but I was just wondering if there where some ways to prevent dangling types here. And behold; there are.

Comment: @RickyA While the solution from metakeule works, it is a bad idea and highly unidiomatic. It slows down your code with the only advantage being a tiny bit of extra protection against programmer stupidity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiom used in the Go standard library is:

`package bar`

```
package bar

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Bar struct {
    a string
    b string
}

func New(baz string) *Bar {
    return &Bar{a: baz, b: baz + baz}
}

func (b *Bar) BzzBar() {
    fmt.Println(*b)
}
```

`package main`

```
package main

import (
    "bar"
)

func main() {
    x := bar.New("sad") //all bars should be created with this
    x.BzzBar()
    // error: unknown bar.Bar field 'A' in struct literal
    // y := bar.Bar{A: "fadss"} //and this should be disallowed
}
```

Output:

```
{sad sadsad}
```

ADDENDUM:

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [The zero value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)
>
> When memory is allocated to store a value, either through a
>   declaration or a call of make or new, and no explicit initialization
>   is provided, the memory is given a default initialization. Each
>   element of such a value is set to the zero value for its type: false
>   for booleans, 0 for integers, 0.0 for floats, "" for strings, and nil
>   for pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps. This
>   initialization is done recursively, so for instance each element of an
>   array of structs will have its fields zeroed if no value is specified.

Another idiom used in the Go standard library is to make zero values meaningful. For example, if `new` has not been explicitly initialized it will have the zero value default of `false`.

```
type Bar struct {
    new bool
    a   string
    b   string
}
```

For example,

```
package bar

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Bar struct {
    new bool
    a   string
    b   string
}

func New(baz string) *Bar {
    return &Bar{new: true, a: baz, b: baz + baz}
}

func (b *Bar) notnew() {
    if b == nil || !b.new {
        panic("bar.Bar not bar.New")
    }
}

func (b *Bar) Bzz() {
    b.notnew()
    fmt.Println(*b)
}
```

.

```
package main

import (
    "bar"
)

func main() {
    x := bar.New("sad") //all bars should be created with this
    x.Bzz()
    // error: unknown bar.Bar field 'A' in struct literal
    // y := bar.Bar{A: "fadss"} //and this should be disallowed

    // var b bar.Bar
    // panic: bar.Bar not bar.New
    // b.Bzz()

    // var b = bar.Bar{}
    // panic: bar.Bar not bar.New
    // b.Bzz()

    // var bp *bar.Bar
    // panic: bar.Bar not bar.New
    // bp.Bzz()

    // var bp = new(bar.Bar)
    // panic: bar.Bar not bar.New
    // bp.Bzz()
}
```

Output:

```
{true sad sadsad}
```

Comment: Mmm; yes it is standard go idiom; yes it works in terms of hiding the fields; but `y := Bar{}` still flies along happily. I guess the real answer here is: just live with it.

Comment: @RickyA: Then let's make `b := bar.Bar{}` crash on use. See my revised answer.

Comment: For being the standard go idiom and showing a method to have this fail, you get the accepted answer.

Comment: @peterSO I find your ADDENDUM bad because it does not fail on initialization time, but when a method is called. That might be at a code far away from the initialization, making it hard to fix. Also you must call `b.notnew()` in every exported method of *Bar.

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to prevent `Bar{}` or `Bar{A: "foo"}`.

To control a struct the way you want you can return an interface instead and not export the struct itself.

Example given:

```
package bar

type Bar interface{
    A() string
    B() string
    // if you need setters
    SetA(string)
    SetB(string)
}

type bar struct {
    a string
    b string
}

func (b *bar) A() string { return b.a }
func (b *bar) B() string { return b.b }

func (b *bar) SetA(val string) { b.a = val }
func (b *bar) SetB(val string) { b.b = val }

func NewBar(baz string) Bar {
    return &bar{a:baz, b:baz+baz}
}
```

Comment: Useless interfaces are not idiomatic, this is not java and you should just trust the user of your package. If it is just a change in code that requires the now new `NewBar` rather than `Bar{}` you can use your editors tools to find and fix these cases.

Comment: @Wessie don't let the your blind hatred of getters/and setters get in the way here. Believe me, I share your dislike, but this is the idiomatic way to hide struct initialization from a user. It should been used as less as possible, but it is very useful if the user cannot create a meaningful type with the `Bar{..}` idiom, and you would therefore not expose him/her to it.

Comment: @RickyA no, because I don't believe in the requirement of hiding the struct initialization to begin with. Neither does the standard library as [`time.Ticker`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker) is a nice example of.

Comment: Although this approach works and is supported by language features, the approach is not used in the standard library and is therefore not idiomatic.

Comment: To not get into religious wars about what is idiomatic or not, I removed the "idiomatic" phrasing. Still finding it more apropriate than the "hacky" "idiomatic" answer from peterSO

Comment: @metakeule: The first flaw in your solution is that it is not valid Go; it doesn't compile.

Comment: @peterSO Fixed the typo. But that was just an example no production code anyway.

Comment: You're going the right way about it @metakeule. Ignore the purists.

Answer (score 4):

You can make all `Bar` fields unexported and provide getters and setters for them. This way package users will still be able to do silly things like

```
a := Bar{}
b := Bar{"foo"}
```

neither or which seems useful (although the former can be used to create an empty `Bar` similar to `&bytes.Buffer{}`).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to not export `A` and `B`, if you provide a `String()` function:

```
type Bar struct {
    a string
    b string
}
func NewBar(baz string) Bar{
    return Bar{a:baz, b:baz+baz}
}
func (Bar) String() string {
  return a + " " b
}
```